# All $L^2(\Omega)$ functions that are $0$ at $\partial\Omega$, definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

I am opening this as a separate question.

Let $\Omega$ be an open and bounded domain. Consider:
$$L_{00}^2 = \{q \in L^2(\Omega)\, |\, q(x)=0 \forall x\in\partial\Omega\}.$$

Why does this space definition not make sense? The fact is that there are many functions in $L^2(\Omega)$ that are $0$ at the boundary.

For example consider $\Omega = (-1,1)$, $x\in\Omega$, and:

$$
  f(x) = \cases{        1       & $-0.7 < x < 0.7$ \cr
                 0 & otherwise}
$$

Here $f(x)$ is obviously in $L^2(\Omega)$ and it vanishes on the boundary. How is it possible that $f \not\in L^2_{00}$?

Is it possible to come up with another definition of $L^2_{00}$ that would make sense?

Comment: My guess is that it is not necessarily true that $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ will be defined on the boundary, if $\partial \Omega \not \subseteq \Omega$.

Comment: What if I consider those $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ that are defined on the boundary? How could I redefine $L^2_{00}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Elements of $L^2(\Omega)$ are not functions. They are equivalence classes of (measurable) functions under the equivalence relation of being equal almost everywhere. This means that changing the "function" on a measure 0 set does not change the element of $L^2$ that you are considering.

Comment: Thanks! So if I instead demand that the L2 “function” is equal 0 in all epsilon balls, each having a center in $\partial\Omega$, then this would actually change an element of $L^2$? Is that how I could potentially redefine my $L^2_{00}$?

Comment: You might be interested in the notion of the essential support of $f$. I'm not sure what you are trying to do but if all that you want to express is the quality that "$f = 0$ near the boundary of $\Omega$" then this could be captured by insisting that the distance between the essential support of $f$ and $\partial \Omega$ is strictly positive.